# Android - изменение цвета текста во время его набора

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Мне надо изменить цвет текста во время его набора, т.е. я пишу в EditText "Hello world" , программа должна Hello делать, к примеру, красным, при этом ввод ещё не закончился. То есть как только я написал Hello и поставил пробел, то это слово становится красным.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592633/android-edittext-spannable-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mEditText;
    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                                          int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                                      int before, int count) {
                String mString = s.toString();
                if(mString.contains(" ")) // реализовать более сложно условие
                    mEditText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                mTextView.setText(s);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, М.С.Тупницкий, у тебя несомненно правильное решения, но я уже нашел немного другое, делал через afterTextChanged, где переменная s содержала нужный текст.